# Agregar API en react js

Tags: reactjs, api, smtp

estoy haciendo un proyecto con la api de smtp.js, el sitio te provee una etiqueta script para poder acceder al cdn, algo asi
`<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>`
el problema es que al llamar el metodo de la api, no me reconoce la variable de Email como parte del proyecto y me saca un error.

```
Email.send({
Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
Username : "username",
Password : "password",
To : 'them@website.com',
From : "you@isp.com",
Subject : "This is the subject",
Body : "And this is the body"
}).then(
message => alert(message)
);
```

Comment: ¿Desde donde estás llamando a `Email`? Desde html o js?

Comment: desde el jsx donde tengo el formulario que usa el método de email, pero no logro hacer que react lo reconozca.

Comment: No esta el paquete en npm?

Comment: Busque el modulo en la pagina pero al parecer no hay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya logre solucionar el error, el problema principal estaba en la sintaxis y las dependencias que tenia el CDN, reescribí el código corrigiendo los errores que me marcaba en el navegador, lo exporte como modulo y finalmente quedo así.

```js
let XDomainRequest
var Email = {
  send: function(a) {
      return new Promise(function(n, e) {
          a.nocache = Math.floor(1e6 * Math.random() + 1)
          a.Action = "Send";
          var t = JSON.stringify(a);
          Email.ajaxPost("https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtpjs.aspx?", t, function(e) {
              n(e)
          })
      })
  },
  ajaxPost: function(e, n, t) {
      var a = Email.createCORSRequest("POST", e);
      a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
      a.onload = function() {
          var e = a.responseText;
          null != t && t(e)
      }
      a.send(n)
  },
  ajax: function(e, n) {
      var t = Email.createCORSRequest("GET", e);
      t.onload = function() {
          var e = t.responseText;
          null != n && n(e)
      }
      t.send()
  },
  createCORSRequest: function(e, n) {
      var t = new XMLHttpRequest;
      return "withCredentials" in t ? t.open(e, n, !0) : "undefined" != typeof XDomainRequest ? (t = new XDomainRequest).open(e, n) : t = null, t
  }
};

export {Email as Email}
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberías importarlo como modulo.

**Solución a tu problema**

Si lo estás metiendo en un script en la cabecera y dicho script expone una variable, como es tu caso, puedes acceder a ella desde window.Email

Comment: hola, ya cree un nuevo js y exporte el código desde ahí hasta el componente donde quiero usarlo, pero el problema persiste.

Line 5:13:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 14:9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 21:9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: ¿Puedes reproducirlo en codesandbox para echarle un vistazo? Sin ver todo junto, dificil